# Resharper displaying NSubstitute methods as errors

Tags: resharper, nsubstitute

We have upgraded to Resharper 7.1 with VS2012. However Resharper seems to display NSubstitute methods as unrecognised in red as shown in the diagram below with Arg.Any<>:

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Note: The codes compiles successfully, its just the display by resharper thats the issue.

Cheers,
Billy

Comment: Have you tried clearing your ReSharper cache? Options > Environment > General > Clear Caches. Also, Try cleaning the solution and rebuilding

Comment: You could also try uninstalling and then reinstalling the NSubstitute Nuget package

Comment: Clearing the cache resolved the issue, cheers levelnis

Comment: Grand - I'll add that as an answer then so you can close it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing your ReSharper cache should fix the problem. Just go to ReSharper > Options > Environment > General > Clear Caches

[image]